# How to show the 'create' view with values filled in

Tags: python, flask-admin

I would like to show the create view for a model

```
url_for('user.create_view')
```

But I want certain values of the form to be already filled in.  I'm not talking about default values in the model, it should be programmable.

```
 url_for('user.create_view', first_name='Jef', last_name='Deelkens')
```

At first sight, I am forced to override the `create_view` method in the ModelView.  But it seems that would require a complete re-implementation of the create functionality, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In your form method you can do:

```
form.first_name.data = 'Jef'
```

This will set the value the user will see when viewing the form. Just make sure to set it after the validate section. Otherwise the user values will be overwritten by the default values

```
def create_view():
  form = new_form()
  if form.validate():
     validation
  form.first_name.data = 'Jef'
  form.last_name.data = 'Deelkens'
  return render_template('create_user', form=form)
```

Comment: I would have to write `new_form()` myself here, right?  And also make a `create_user` template?

Comment: You should yes. That way you can add validation to the inputs. Rather than letting a user enter any value and relying on the database to catch invalid input